# Send error report option in datapower is not working

Tags: ibm-datapower

I tried to send the error report to my email account using the send error report option available in datapower XB62 appliance but i didn't receive any emails in spite of the action being successful in datapower.

I check the email SMTP settings and it was as follows :

SMTP Setting :

Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: TLS

In datapower the following details were used in send error report option :

SMTP Server : smtp.office365.com

Subject : TestReport

Email Address : XXXXX@YYY.com

Email Sender Address : ZZZZZ@YYY.com

The below message was displayed when i send the error report :

Send error report to 'XXXXX@YYY.com' using 'smtp.office365.com'?

i confirmed the action, i received a message Action completed successfully.

Still I didn't find anything in my mail box.

Comment: I checked the setting under System --> Failure Notification

 Date Created   Reason  Upload Status  Location 
20160505074223801BST  user-requested  failure  dpsmtp://smtp.office365.com/?To=XXXXX%40YYY.com . The notification is set to failure, so is that i will get notification in case of any errors ? Is it possible to get success reports as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the report can be quite big so it might be size restrictions on your mail. Look in temp log directory of DataPower to find the size of the report.